# FastAPI - Unable to render Swagger in production

Tags: swagger, openapi, fastapi

This is my FastAPI `main.py` file.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from project.config.settings import base as settings

app = FastAPI(docs_url=f"{settings.URL_ROOT}/{settings.DOCS_URL}", redoc_url=None)
app.openapi_version = "3.0.0"

# some functions here
```

And I deployed this project to a server. But when I go to address of docs in my server, `1.2.3.4/url_root/docs_url`, it shows me following message:

```
Unable to render this definition
The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.

Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field.
Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).
```

What's the problem and how can I solve it?

**UPDATE:**
FastAPI is behind Nginx. All of my endpoints are working correctly, but I cannot see docs.

Comment: Please share all the dependencies used for the project. FastAPI has inbuild support for Swagger. Also share the full code or link where the code is available

Comment: could you find a solution for this?

Comment: @CFD No, I ignored this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check this [page](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/#proxy-with-a-stripped-path-prefix) for proxy settings.

but as far as i understand, you can fix this by just adding root_path to openapi_url:

```
app = FastAPI(
    docs_url=f"/url_root/docs_url",
    openapi_url="/url_root/openapi.json",
    redoc_url=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't rewrite the URL in the location block if you use nginx, and add /url_root to all the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem having a similar architecture: nginx proxying fastapi running on port `8000` through the `/api` path. I was able to solve the problem using the `root_path` parameter as stated in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/#proxy-with-a-stripped-path-prefix).

My final nginx site configuration looks something like:

```
        location /api {
#               ...
                rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
#               ...
        }
```

And my `main.py` file looks something like this when creating the FastAPI instance:

```
app = FastAPI(
    root_url="/api"
    # some other params
)
```

After this change, when I check the url on the local environment I get this screen:

[image]

But... when I check it on my web site I get the docs:

[image]

I hope this helps!